# How can I pass data to an Angular component with attribute?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I wanna create a component, which looks like:

```
<component something></component>
```

Where something is boolean, which used inside of the component. I couldn't find any reference for this. How can I do that?

Comment: You can find an exemple in the angular tutorial : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3

Comment: You need to use Input

Comment: `@Input() something  =  false` in the component